# Truncate timestamp to arbitrary intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I want to plot `my_values` with some lower resolution on the time axis than I have in the database. I use something like the following SQL to get the average values per time interval (e.g., an hour):

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', my_timestamps) AS my_time_lowres
     , AVG(my_values) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY my_time_lowres
```

---

Using `date_trunc()` it is possible to reduce the resolution of the timestamp to a certain degree (according to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html)):

```
select date_trunc('hour', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40') 
-- the output is: 2001-02-16 20:00:00
```

This way, I can do this for the following interval sizes (and some larger/smaller sizes):

```
...
second
minute
hour
day
week
...
```

---

Is there a way to achieve this for other time intervals as well, e.g., 3 hours, 6 hours?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this demo to bring timestamps down to a resolution of 15 minutes and aggregate resulting dupes:

```
WITH tbl(id, ts) AS ( VALUES
    (1::int, '2012-10-04 00:00:00'::timestamp)
   ,(2, '2012-10-04 18:23:01')
   ,(3, '2012-10-04 18:30:00')
   ,(4, '2012-10-04 18:52:33')
   ,(5, '2012-10-04 18:55:01')
   ,(6, '2012-10-04 18:59:59')
   ,(7, '2012-10-05 11:01:01')
   )
SELECT to_timestamp((extract(epoch FROM ts)::bigint / 900)*900)::timestamp
                                                            AS lower_bound
     , to_timestamp(avg(extract(epoch FROM ts)))::timestamp AS avg_ts
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Result:

```
     lower_bound     |       avg_ts        | ct
---------------------+---------------------+----
 2012-10-04 00:00:00 | 2012-10-04 00:00:00 |  1
 2012-10-04 18:15:00 | 2012-10-04 18:23:01 |  1
 2012-10-04 18:30:00 | 2012-10-04 18:30:00 |  1
 2012-10-04 18:45:00 | 2012-10-04 18:55:51 |  3
 2012-10-05 11:00:00 | 2012-10-05 11:01:01 |  1
```

The trick is to extract a unix epoch like @Michael already posted. Integer division lumps them together in buckets of the chosen resolution, because fractional digits are truncated.

I divide by 900, because 15 minutes = 900 seconds.

Multiply by the same number to get the resulting `lower_bound`.
Convert the unix epoch back to a timestamp with [**`to_timestamp()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html).

This works great for intervals that can be represented without fractional digits in the decimal system. For even more versatility use the often overlooked function [**`width_bucket()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html) like I demonstrate in this [recent, closely related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642239/939860). More explanation, links and an sqlfiddle demo over there.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to the number of seconds since epoch and go for integer division by 3*3600, 6*3600, etc.