# calculating average with grouping based on time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a postgres table I have store the speed of an object with a 10 seconds interval. The values are not available for every 10 seconds during the day; so it could be that there is no line for today 16:39:40

How would the query look like to get an relation containing the average of the speed for 1 minute (or 30sec or n-sec) intervals for a given day, assuming the non-existing rows mean a speed of 0.

**speed_table**
id (*int*, pk)
ts (timestamp)
speed (numeric)

I've built this query but am getting stuck on some important parts:

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('minute', ts) AS truncated, 
    avg(speed)
FROM speed_table AS t 
WHERE ts >= '2014-06-21 00:00:00'
AND ts <= '2014-06-21 23:59:59'
AND condition2 = 'something'
GROUP BY date_trunc('minute', ts)
ORDER BY truncated
```

- How can I alter the interval in something other then the result of the date_trunc function eg 5 minutes of 30 seconds?
- How can I add the not available rows for the remaining of the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simple and fast solution for this particular example:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', ts) AS minute
     , sum(speed)/6 AS avg_speed
FROM   speed_table AS t 
WHERE  ts >= '2014-06-21 0:0'
AND    ts <  '2014-06-20 0:0'  -- exclude dangling corner case
AND    condition2 = 'something'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

You need to factor in missing rows as "0 speed". Since a minute has 6 samples, just sum and divide by 6. Missing rows evaluate to `0` implicitly.

This returns no row for minutes with no rows at all.`avg_speed` for missing result rows is `0`.

#### General query for arbitrary intervals

Works for all any interval listed in [the manual for `date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', g.ts) AS ts_start
     , avg(COALESCE(speed, 0))    AS avg_speed
FROM  (SELECT generate_series('2014-06-21 0:0'::timestamp
                            , '2014-06-22 0:0'::timestamp
                            , '10 sec'::interval) AS ts) g
LEFT   JOIN speed_table t USING (ts)
WHERE (t.condition2 = 'something' OR
       t.condition2 IS NULL)                -- depends on actual condition!
AND    g.ts <> '2014-06-22 0:0'::timestamp  -- exclude dangling corner case
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The problematic part is the additional unknown condition. You would need to define that. And decide whether missing rows supplied by generate_series should pass the test or not (which can be tricky!).
I let them pass in my example (and all other rows with a NULL values).

Compare:
[PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Arbitrary intervals:
[Truncate timestamp to arbitrary intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730072/truncate-timestamp-to-arbitrary-intervals/12731753#12731753)

For completely arbitrary intervals consider [@Clodoaldo's math based on epoch values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24343206/939860) or use the often overlooked function [`width_bucket()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html). Example:
[Aggregating (x,y) coordinate point clouds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641764/aggregating-x-y-coordinate-point-clouds-in-postgresql/12642239#12642239)
[Aggregating (x,y) coordinate point clouds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641764/aggregating-x-y-coordinate-point-clouds-in-postgresql/12642239#12642239)

Comment: The unknown condition is just a integer selector: eg `where t.objectid= 56`

Comment: @stUrb: The tricky parts: Can `t.objectid` be NULL? Do we assume missing rows to fulfill the condition? What's the difference between a row that is removed by the condition and a row that is just not there?

Comment: The object id cannot be NULL. The tables stores the speed of multiple assets. The object_id just separates the different assests.

Answer (score 2):

If you had issued some data it would be possible to test so this can contain errors. Point them including the error message so I can fix.

```
select
    to_timestamp(
        (extract(epoch from ts)::integer / (60 * 2)) * (60 * 2)
    ) as truncated,
    avg(coalesce(speed, 0)) as avg_speed
from
    generate_series (
        '2014-06-21 00:00:00'::timestamp,
        '2014-06-22'::timestamp - interval '1 second',
        '10 seconds'
    ) ts (ts)
    left join
    speed_table t on ts.ts = t.ts and condition2 = 'something'
group by 1
order by 1
```

The example is grouped by 30 seconds. It is number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` (`epoch`) divided by 120. When you want to group by 5 minutes divide it by 12 (60 / 5).

The `generate_series` in the example is generating timestamps at 1 second interval. It is `left outer join`ed to the speed table so it fills the gaps. When the speed is null then coalesce returns 0.