# Select minimum value from each 1 hour block

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have data: timestamp, value.

```
CREATE TABLE cgl
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('cgl_id_seq'::regclass),
    ts integer,
    value integer
)
```

I want to have minimum value from each 1 hour. There is unknown number of records per hour.
I know more or less (rather less) I should use partition. Please point me to some examples or directions.

Comment: how do you know which elements fall into the same hour if you don't have a `timestamp` in your table?

Comment: Field `ts` is timestamp

Comment: Then please fix your question.

Comment: `int` is not a `timestamp` those are two very different data types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ts` is supposed to be type `timestamp`:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('hour', ts) AS hour, min(value) AS min_val
FROM   cgl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) truncates timestamps to the hour. Of course, you get no row for hours without any data from this. If you need a row for *every hour, generate a total set of hours with `generate_series()` first. Example:

- [Join a count query on a generate_series in postgres and also retrieve Null-values as "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413715/join-a-count-query-on-a-generate-series-in-postgres-and-also-retrieve-null-value/13414797#13414797)

If `ts` is in fact `integer`, it's probably supposed to be a UNIX epoch, and you need to convert it with [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) first:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(ts)) AS hour, min(value) AS min_val
FROM   cgl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Consider storing a proper timestamp to begin with.

Aside: "partition" would hint at window functions, which would be the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Thank you. Is it still optimal for use with different periods like 15minutes? I'll also need to take first and last record from each set. And max - to draw a candle chart.

Comment: @koral: `date:trunc()` only covers basic time units. For 15-min intervals you need a different approach, depending on additional undisclosed information. Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15577413/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731753/939860 or start a new question will all defining info.