# How to get Postgres records in higher date resolution (4 hours, 1 day, 1 week, 1 month - hourly, daily. monthly) from 1 hour timestamp table

Tags: postgresql, date

Given the following table, which is segmented into 1-hour intervals:

```
| id  | created_at                    | tt | vv  |
| --- | ----------------------------- | -- | --- |
| 1   | 2021-05-08 16:00:01.384687+00 | A  | 100 |
| 2   | 2021-05-08 16:00:03.435737+00 | B  | 50  |
| 3   | 2021-05-08 17:01:00.388957+00 | A  | 101 |
| 4   | 2021-05-08 17:02:00.43814+00  | B  | 49  |
| 5   | 2021-05-08 18:00:30.685336+00 | A  | 102 |
| 6   | 2021-05-08 18:00:40.731571+00 | B  | 48  |
| 7   | 2021-05-08 19:01:02.566949+00 | A  | 103 |
| 8   | 2021-05-08 19:02:00.576785+00 | B  | 47  |
| 9   | 2021-05-08 20:03:10.566949+00 | A  | 104 |
| 10  | 2021-05-08 20:05:00.576785+00 | B  | 46  |
```

where:

- id is the *primary key*;
- created_at is a *timestamp* with tz;
- tt is a *string / text*; and
- vv is a numeric

I am looking for the Postgres **query string** to obtain the data (created_at, tt, vv) segmented as **2-hour / 4-hour / 24-hour / 1-week / 1-month intervals**. Example result table for 2-hour intervals would therefore be:

```
| id  | created_at                    | tt   | vv  |
| --- | ----------------------------- | ---- | --- |
| 1   | 2021-05-08 16:00:00.000000+00 | A    | 100 |
| 2   | 2021-05-08 16:00:00.000000+00 | B    | 50  |
| 5   | 2021-05-08 18:00:00.000000+00 | A    | 102 |
| 6   | 2021-05-08 18:00:00.000000+00 | B    | 48  |
| 9   | 2021-05-08 20:00:00.000000+00 | A    | 104 |
| 10  | 2021-05-08 20:00:00.000000+00 | B    | 46  |
```

I have tried utilizing a interval timeline as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730072/truncate-timestamp-to-arbitrary-intervals/12731753) and combining it with a WITH statement unsuccessfully. **NOTE**: I am **NOT** looking for a sum column, but an aggregation as stated in the table above.

Output should therefore have the same structure as when using

```
SELECT date_trunc('second', created_at) as time, tt, vv FROM tbl GROUP BY created_at, tt, vv order by time desc
```

Bonus if interval can be flexibly specified in ms or s. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by year,month day and hour, see belowexamples

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   "id" INTEGER,
>   "created_at" timestamp,
>   "tt" VARCHAR(1),
>   "vv" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   ("id", "created_at", "tt", "vv")
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2021-05-08 16:00:01.384687+00', 'A', '100'),
>   ('2', '2021-05-08 16:00:03.435737+00', 'B', '50'),
>   ('3', '2021-05-08 17:01:00.388957+00', 'A', '101'),
>   ('4', '2021-05-08 17:02:00.43814+00', 'B', '49'),
>   ('5', '2021-05-08 18:00:30.685336+00', 'A', '102'),
>   ('6', '2021-05-08 18:00:40.731571+00', 'B', '48'),
>   ('7', '2021-05-08 19:01:02.566949+00', 'A', '103'),
>   ('8', '2021-05-08 19:02:00.576785+00', 'B', '47'),
>   ('9', '2021-05-08 20:03:10.566949+00', 'A', '104'),
>   ('10', '2021-05-08 20:05:00.576785+00', 'B', '46');
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
> SELECT 
> "id", "created_at", "tt", "vv",
>   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
>       PARTITION BY "tt"
> ,EXTRACT(year from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(Month from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(day from  "created_at")
> ,trunc(EXTRACT(hour from  "created_at") / 2)
>       ORDER BY
>           "created_at"
>   ) as rown
>   FROM table1)
> SELECT "id", date_trunc('hour',"created_at"), "tt", "vv"
> FROM CTE 
> WHERE CTE.rown = 1
> ORDER BY "id"
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date_trunc          | tt |  vv
> -: | :------------------ | :- | --:
>  1 | 2021-05-08 16:00:00 | A  | 100
>  2 | 2021-05-08 16:00:00 | B  |  50
>  5 | 2021-05-08 18:00:00 | A  | 102
>  6 | 2021-05-08 18:00:00 | B  |  48
>  9 | 2021-05-08 20:00:00 | A  | 104
> 10 | 2021-05-08 20:00:00 | B  |  46
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> "id", "created_at", "tt", "vv",
>   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
>       PARTITION BY "tt"
> ,EXTRACT(year from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(Month from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(day from  "created_at")
> ,trunc(EXTRACT(hour from  "created_at") / 2)
>       ORDER BY
>           "created_at"
>   ) as rown
>   FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | created_at                 | tt |  vv | rown
> -: | :------------------------- | :- | --: | ---:
>  1 | 2021-05-08 16:00:01.384687 | A  | 100 |    1
>  3 | 2021-05-08 17:01:00.388957 | A  | 101 |    2
>  5 | 2021-05-08 18:00:30.685336 | A  | 102 |    1
>  7 | 2021-05-08 19:01:02.566949 | A  | 103 |    2
>  9 | 2021-05-08 20:03:10.566949 | A  | 104 |    1
>  2 | 2021-05-08 16:00:03.435737 | B  |  50 |    1
>  4 | 2021-05-08 17:02:00.43814  | B  |  49 |    2
>  6 | 2021-05-08 18:00:40.731571 | B  |  48 |    1
>  8 | 2021-05-08 19:02:00.576785 | B  |  47 |    2
> 10 | 2021-05-08 20:05:00.576785 | B  |  46 |    1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> MIN("id"), MIN("created_at"), "tt", SUM("vv")
>
> FROM table1 
> group by "tt"
> ,EXTRACT(year from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(Month from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(day from  "created_at")
> ,trunc(EXTRACT(hour from  "created_at") / 2)
> ```
>
> ```
> min | min                        | tt | sum
> --: | :------------------------- | :- | --:
>   5 | 2021-05-08 18:00:30.685336 | A  | 205
>   1 | 2021-05-08 16:00:01.384687 | A  | 201
>  10 | 2021-05-08 20:05:00.576785 | B  |  46
>   6 | 2021-05-08 18:00:40.731571 | B  |  95
>   2 | 2021-05-08 16:00:03.435737 | B  |  99
>   9 | 2021-05-08 20:03:10.566949 | A  | 104
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> MIN("id"), MIN("created_at"), "tt", SUM("vv")
>
> FROM table1 
> group by "tt"
> ,EXTRACT(year from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(Month from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(day from  "created_at")
> ,trunc(EXTRACT(hour from  "created_at") / 4)
> ```
>
> ```
> min | min                        | tt | sum
> --: | :------------------------- | :- | --:
>   1 | 2021-05-08 16:00:01.384687 | A  | 406
>   9 | 2021-05-08 20:03:10.566949 | A  | 104
>  10 | 2021-05-08 20:05:00.576785 | B  |  46
>   2 | 2021-05-08 16:00:03.435737 | B  | 194
> ```

> ```
> ;SELECT 
> MIN("id"), MIN("created_at"), "tt", SUM("vv")
>
> FROM table1 
> group by "tt"
> ,EXTRACT(year from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(Month from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(day from  "created_at")
> ```
>
> ```
> min | min                        | tt | sum
> --: | :------------------------- | :- | --:
>   1 | 2021-05-08 16:00:01.384687 | A  | 510
>   2 | 2021-05-08 16:00:03.435737 | B  | 240
> ```

> ```
> ;SELECT 
> MIN("id"), MIN("created_at"), "tt", SUM("vv")
>
> FROM table1 
> group by "tt"
> ,EXTRACT(year from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(Month from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(week from "created_at")
> ```
>
> ```
> min | min                        | tt | sum
> --: | :------------------------- | :- | --:
>   1 | 2021-05-08 16:00:01.384687 | A  | 510
>   2 | 2021-05-08 16:00:03.435737 | B  | 240
> ```

> ```
> ;SELECT 
> MIN("id"), MIN("created_at"), "tt", SUM("vv")
>
> FROM table1 
> group by "tt"
> ,EXTRACT(year from  "created_at")
> ,EXTRACT(Month from  "created_at")
> ```
>
> ```
> min | min                        | tt | sum
> --: | :------------------------- | :- | --:
>   2 | 2021-05-08 16:00:03.435737 | B  | 240
>   1 | 2021-05-08 16:00:01.384687 | A  | 510
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f405a4d0a38052c92042ce4201957cac)*

Comment: Great, what if I don't want the sum but "vv" instead?

Comment: All columns in the Select must be in the GROUP By or have a aggregation function, the sum and MIN are only for demonstration purposes else it would give an error. ,but that wasn't your question, if you a´want to know something else then dates ask an new one and accept the answer

Comment: I gave an example query for the result (which includes vv, not sum) and an example result table (which includes vv, not sum).

Comment: I'd like to accept the answer and appreciate the effort but it's just not useful without the vv column.

Comment: I have accepted the answer because it provides the segmentation in combination with a "SELECT * from x" query. I would still be looking for a solution that outputs the result required above in ONE query. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: add a row number to the result and then select the first i think, after work i make a sample if you have a problem with it

Comment: @pspray see the first query it shows you how to wsolve your wanted result, the rest espeial the part where you partition, you find in the select privious posted