# Multiple averages over evenly spaced intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, average, window-functions

I'm trying to learn SQL so be patient with me. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3

I want to average a column based on a window of dates. I've been able to write window functions that accomplish this with a set `interval` but I'd like to be able to be able to do this with a growing `interval`. By this I mean:

```
average values from date_0 to date_1
average values from date_0 to date_2
average values from date_0 to date_3
..... so date date_0 stays the same and date_x grows and creates a larger sample
```

I'm assuming there is a better way than running a query for each range I'd like to average. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

#### EDIT

I'm trying to create evenly spaced bins to be used to aggregate values of a table over.
I come to the interval by:

```
(MAX(date) - MIN(date)) / bins
```

where `date` is the column of a table
and  `bins` is the number of bins I'd like to divide the table into.

`date_0` = MIN(date)
`date_n` = MIN(date) + (interval * n)

Comment: Where do `date_1 .. date_n` come from? Regular intervals? Or another table?

Comment: Erwin I edited the question in an attempt to answer your interval question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the handy function **[`width_bucket()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html)**:

To get the average for each time segment ("bin"):

```
SELECT width_bucket(extract(epoch FROM t.the_date)
                  , x.min_epoch, x.max_epoch, x.bins) AS bin
     , avg(value) AS bin_avg
FROM   tbl t
    , (SELECT extract(epoch FROM min(the_date)) AS min_epoch
            , extract(epoch FROM max(the_date)) AS max_epoch
            , 10 AS bins
       FROM   tbl t
      ) x
GROUP  BY 1;
```

To get the "running average" over the (step-by-step) growing time interval:

```
SELECT bin, round(sum(bin_sum) OVER w /sum(bin_ct) OVER w, 2) AS running_avg
FROM  (
   SELECT width_bucket(extract(epoch FROM t.the_date)
                     , x.min_epoch, x.max_epoch, x.bins) AS bin
        , sum(value) AS bin_sum
        , count(*)   AS bin_ct
   FROM   tbl t
       , (SELECT extract(epoch FROM min(the_date)) AS min_epoch
               , extract(epoch FROM max(the_date)) AS max_epoch
               , 10 AS bins
          FROM   tbl t
         ) x
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY bin)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Using `the_date` instead of `date` as column name, avoiding [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers.
Since `width_bucket()` is currently only implemented for `double precision` and `numeric`, I extract epoch values from `the_date`. Details here:
[Aggregating (x,y) coordinate point clouds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641764/aggregating-x-y-coordinate-point-clouds-in-postgresql/12642239#12642239)

Comment: I keep getting "ERROR:  function width_bucket(date, date, date, integer) does not exist.    HINT:   No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: @user3204587: My oversight. `width_bucket()` is only implemented for `dp` and `numeric`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm up voting regardless because of how helpful you've been and for introducing me to `width_bucket()` but this is returning the average over the constant interval of a bucket correct? Not the growing interval from date_0 to date_n where date_n = MIN(the_date) + (interval * n)?

Comment: @user3204587: This returns the average for each of ten equally long time intervals covering the complete time range in the table. Should be what the Q asks for. Ah! .. now I get it, your intervals all start from `date_0` ...

Comment: @user3204587: Added a solution to compute average values for your "growing intervals".

Answer (score 3):

If you have a set of data, you can readily get what you want in separate columns:

```
select avg(case when date between date_0 and date_1 then value end) as avg1,
       avg(case when date between date_0 and date_2 then value end) as avg2,
       . . .
       avg(case when date between date_0 and date_n then value end) as avgn            
from table t
where date >= date_0;
```