# PostgreSQL window function with LIMIT

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, sql-limit

The query below groups the results from `first` into 4 equally spaced date bins and aggregates an average for `the_value` in each bin.

```
WITH first as(
SELECT
    extract(EPOCH FROM foo.t_date) as the_date,
    foo_val as the_value
FROM bar
INNER JOIN foo
ON
    foo.user_id = bar.x_id
    and
    foo.user_name = 'xxxx'
)
SELECT bin, round(sum(bin_sum) OVER w /sum(bin_ct) OVER w, 2) AS running_avg
FROM  (
   SELECT width_bucket(first.the_date
                     , x.min_epoch, x.max_epoch, x.bins) AS bin
        , sum(first.the_value) AS bin_sum
        , count(*)   AS bin_ct
   FROM   first
       , (SELECT MIN(first.the_date) AS min_epoch
               , MAX(first.the_date) AS max_epoch
               , 4 AS bins
          FROM  first
         ) x
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY bin)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

I would like to be able to only calculate the average for the lowest say 20 `the_value`'s in each bin. From other posts here on Stackoverflow I have seen that this is possible and that perhaps `ORDER BY the_value` and `rank()` is the best way to go about it. But my struggle is that I'm not sure where my current query should be modified to implement this.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Postgres version 9.3

Comment: _Any insight would be appreciated_ Usable data would be appreciated.

Comment: As well as your version of Postgres (*always*).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - the portion of the above query that acts on `first` was taken from the answer you submitted to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513618/multiple-averages-over-evenly-spaced-intervals).

Comment: @user3204587: I thought it looked familiar. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()` on each bin.
First compute the row number `rn`, then apply `WHERE rn < 21` in the next step:

```
WITH first AS (
   SELECT extract(EPOCH FROM foo.t_date) AS the_date
        , foo_val AS the_value
   FROM bar
   JOIN foo ON foo.user_id = bar.x_id
           AND foo.user_name = 'xxxx'
   )
, x AS (
   SELECT MIN(the_date) AS min_epoch
        , MAX(the_date) AS max_epoch
   FROM  first
   )
, y AS (
   SELECT width_bucket(f.the_date, x.min_epoch, x.max_epoch, 4) AS bin, *
   FROM   first f, x
   )
, z AS (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY bin ORDER BY the_value) AS rn, *
   FROM   y
   )
SELECT bin, round(sum(bin_sum) OVER w / sum(bin_ct) OVER w, 2) AS running_avg
FROM  (
   SELECT bin
        , sum(the_value) AS bin_sum
        , count(*)       AS bin_ct
   FROM   z
   WHERE  rn < 21   -- max 20 lowest values
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY bin)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

CTEs `y` and `z` could be conflated. Similarly `first` and `x` could be conflated.
But it's clearer that way.

Untested, since we don't have test data.

Comment: In the `y AS` portion you write `FROM first f, x` and the fields in width_bucket are preceded by `f.`. Is `first f` == `first as f`?

Comment: @user3204587: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229979/query-to-order-by-the-number-of-rows-returned-from-another-select/20230716#20230716)