# PostgreSQL - Get count of items in a table grouped by a datetime column for N intervals

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a User table, where there are the following fields.

```
| id | created_at | username |
```

I want to filter this table so that I can get the number of users who have been created in a datetime range, separated into N intervals. e.g. for users having `created_at` in between `2019-01-01T00:00:00` and `2019-01-02T00:00:00` separated into 2 intervals, I will get something like this.

```
_______________________________
|       dt            | count |
-------------------------------
| 2019-01-01T00:00:00 |   6   |
| 2019-01-01T12:00:00 |   7   |
-------------------------------
```

Is it possible to do so in one hit? I am currently using my Django ORM to create N date ranges and then making N queries, which isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the times you want and then use `left join` and aggregation:

```
select gs.ts, count(u.id)
from generate_series('2019-01-01T00:00:00'::timestamp,
                     '2019-01-01T12:00:00'::timestamp,
                     interval '12 hour'
                    ) gs(ts) left join
     users u
     on u.created_at >= gs.ts and
        u.created_at < gs.ts + interval '12 hour'
group by 1
order by 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want to specify the number of rows, you can use something similar:

```
from generate_series(1, 10, 1) as gs(n) cross join lateral
     (values ('2019-01-01T00:00:00'::timestamp + (gs.n - 1) * interval '12 hour')
     ) v(ts) left join
     users u
     on u.created_at >= v.ts and
        u.created_at < v.ts + interval '12 hour'
```

Comment: Is it possible to give number of rows needed in stead of time interval? If my end date was 2019-01-07 I would get 14 rows for 12 hours whereas I only needed two rows.

Comment: @Mehran . . . You can generate numbers and then construct the timestamps.  I edited the answer to show  one method for doing this.

Comment: yeah, I've done exactly that but not in your way. I've gotten the number of hours required to make the data range divided into the number of intervals I want. So for 4 days and 4 intervals, the hours will be 24 hours, and so on.

Comment: is it possible to get the value  0 when the returned count is null?

Comment: @Mehran . . . This should not return `NULL` for any values.  `COUNT()` does not return `NULL` (well, if can if it is in a subquery that returns no rows, but that is not really the `COUNT()`).

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, there is a dedicated function for this (several overloaded variants, really): [**`width_bucket()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE).

One additional difficulty: it does not work on type `timestamp` directly. But you can work with extracted epoch values like this:

```sql
WITH cte(min_ts, max_ts, buckets) AS (  -- interval and nr of buckets here
   SELECT timestamp '2019-01-01T00:00:00'
        , timestamp '2019-01-02T00:00:00'
        , 2
   )
SELECT width_bucket(extract(epoch FROM t.created_at)
                  , extract(epoch FROM c.min_ts)
                  , extract(epoch FROM c.max_ts)
                  , c.buckets) AS bucket
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   cte c ON t.created_at >= min_ts  -- incl. lower
            AND t.created_at <  max_ts  -- excl. upper
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Empty buckets (intervals with no rows in it) are not returned at all. Your
comment seems to suggest you want that.

**Notably**, this accesses the table **once** - as requested and as opposed to generating intervals first and then joining to the table (repeatedly).

See:

- [How to reduce result rows of SQL query equally in full range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947961/how-to-reduce-result-rows-of-sql-query-equally-in-full-range/36948347#36948347)
- [Aggregating (x,y) coordinate point clouds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641764/aggregating-x-y-coordinate-point-clouds-in-postgresql/12642239#12642239)

That does not yet include effective bounds, just bucket numbers. Actual bounds can be added cheaply:

```sql
WITH cte(min_ts, max_ts, buckets) AS (  -- interval and nr of buckets here
   SELECT timestamp '2019-01-01T00:00:00'
        , timestamp '2019-01-02T00:00:00'
        , 2
   )
SELECT b.*
     , min_ts + ((c.max_ts - c.min_ts) / c.buckets) * (bucket-1) AS lower_bound
FROM  (
   SELECT width_bucket(extract(epoch FROM t.created_at)
                     , extract(epoch FROM c.min_ts)
                     , extract(epoch FROM c.max_ts)
                     , c.buckets) AS bucket
        , count(*) AS ct
   FROM   tbl t
   JOIN   cte c ON t.created_at >= min_ts  -- incl. lower
               AND t.created_at <  max_ts  -- excl. upper
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 1
   ) b, cte c;
```

Now you only change input values in the CTE to adjust results.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=910dcb2ea83c1f7cf940776a52cd1cf8)*